# How to concisely let compiler know what type a value should be and to check it?

Tags: typescript

```
function use(x: any){
  console.log(x);
}

type T = 'A' | 'B';

// consider all above fixed, do NOT change it in your answers (I am not asking about types in parameters of a function...)
// it only simulates what is in real code happening, it's just a minimal example

// works as I want, but requires temporary variable. clutters code quite a lot.
const a: T = 'C'; // <- crashes (compiler throws an error, desired behavior)
use(a);

// doesn't work - tsc happily compiles it and 'C' is assumed to be of type T
use(<T>'C');
use('C' as T);
```

I want some kind of checked expression against type I state. Like `const` does (it will crash if right hand side is not of that type), but without temporary variable - preferably inline, similarily how "type assertion" (type cast) is working now.

Edit1: This is obviously not a real code and my question is strictly about enforcing type check at the position I wrote "doesn't work". Do not change the function, consider it fixed. I know how to use types in functions/vars/lets/consts/interfaces, but that's not what this question is about.

Edit2: Another example:

```
const input: any = 'SomeRealValueB'; // this comes from unsafe place, can't be safely typed without runtime checks which I really don't want to do

// ^ that can't be changed

type SomeRealType = 'SomeRealValueA' | 'SomeRealValueB';

// my current solution I am not happy with (unnecessary variable and line of code)
const someRealValueA: SomeRealType = 'SomeRealValueA';
if(input == someRealValueA) { console.log('y'); }
else { console.log('n'); }

// why I want it typed - consider that after refactoring 'SomeRealValueB' gets changed to 'SomeRealValueC', I want compiler to chceck that for me
```

Comment: You probably don't mean crash, but a TypeScript compilation error (they are not the same thing). Also, what prevents you from defining your constraint in the function `use`?

Comment: @E_net4 Oh, yes, of course, I meant compilation error. In this example nothing is preventing me changing the type, in real code there something is. So please take the function as fixed. (Updated question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no syntax for an inline compile-time type check in TypeScript, as literally asked. I suppose that there isn't that much interest in such a feature, since you can already make one yourself:

```
function check<T>(x: T) { return x; }
```

The following lines would fail individually:

```
check<number>("five");
use(check<Ty>('C'));
```

---

However, it must also be noted that the lack of proper type checks in a function could be hiding a separate issue, and so, functions here is unavoidable. In particular, if your external function `use` takes a parameter as `any`, and by its own semantics should not, then that is just a bad TypeScript declaration, which should be reconsidered and fixed whenever possible. Otherwise, if there is no way that the function's declaration can change, or if new restrictions on the parameter type are just part of your own business logic, then your own application should wrap around it into a safe, type-checked function.

With that said, you have three choices at the moment: (1) use variables, like you did in your question; (2) wrap the function around a new declaration with the intended restrictions:

```
type Ty = 'A' | 'B';
const useTy: (x: Ty) => void = use;

useTy('C'); // Argument of type '"C"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ty'.
```

(3) Or finally, since functions themselves are type-checked, you can make an identity function like the `check` function above and use that.

Comment: I thought about #1 (same approach occurred to me earlier, but I waited to see if anyone could come up with something directly supported by TS). I'll use that. To your other points - that function is only to show the issue, in reality there is `==` and that is not typed when one side is `any` (unless I do some runtime checks I can't safely assume type of that), so I can't really add types to `==` operator. Other solution would be to get rid of union type and replace it with new string enum, unfortunately we have some tools witch rely on string union types :(. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Since Typescript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) you can use the `satisfies` operator to ask the compiler to check that an expression satisfies a given type:

```
// OK
'A' satisfies T

// error
'C' satisfies T
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to do this but:

```
function use<T>(x: T){
  console.log(x);
}
type T = 'A' | 'B';
use<T>('C');
```

give:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"C"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

Better would probably be to make sure that the context where you want to use 'C' is fully typed and then you don't have to start adding your own additional checks.

Comment: That's not what I am asking. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Sadly the context is untyped (`any`) and without doing runtime checks I can't safely assume the type. I want the value on the right side typed (in my case of a `==` operator) to prevent errors when someone changes the `T` (e.g. changing `'A'` to `'Z'` in definition of `T`), but the compiler won't catch it, because left side is untyped so right side can be anything.

Comment: So the solution would be to change the context and get rid of all untyped and 'any' values.

Comment: Can't be done without runtime checks which I won't do (and typing e.g. number as a string to fix issue with language/compiler is IMO very fishy and error prone in future, because who would expect variable of string to hold a number). But I don't want the data checked every time at runtime, I want the literal in code checked at compilation time. Language/compiler should be able to do that...