# How to create a value of a specified type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Type assertion cannot detect missing fields.

First, define a type:

```
type Profile = {
  name: string
}
```

It is easy to declare a variable of this type, and the compiler can check that it is correct:

```
// Error: Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Profile'
let p: Profile = {}
```

But if I create a value directly, the compiler does not report an error:

```
// The fields in Profile are not filled, but the compiler did not report an error
console.log(<Profile>{})
```

I try to use a generic function, and it works:

```
function defineVar<T>(value: T): T {
  return value
}

//Error: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Profile'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Profile'.
console.log(defineVar<Profile>({}))
```

I wonder if there is an easier way?

Comment: The compiler doesn't error because _you're telling it not to_, that's what a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) does. It's not supposed to detect missing fields.

Comment: If you want the compiler to check that a value is of a particular type, you can declare a variable for it like `let obj: Profile = {...};` and then use the variable, or if you don't want a variable for it, you can write `{...} satisfies Profile` in an expression.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the answer I needed. @kaya3

Comment: So do we want to add an answer here (@kaya3?) describing how [type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) work, or close the question?

Comment: @jcalz The question already includes a variable declaration with a type annotation so I'm not sure; [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45061130/12299000) is potentially a good one to use as a duplicate, it didn't previously have an answer mentioning `satisfies` so I've added one.